# How to retrieve items id from an array of object and put it in an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

below is an array of object

```js
const arr_obj = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'items': [
            {
                'id':'1',
                'data': {
                    'id': 3,
                }
             },
             {
                 'id': '2',
                 'data': {
                     'id': 4,
                  }
              }
          ]
      },

      {
          'id': 2,
          'items': [
              {
                  'id':'3',
                  'data': {
                      'id': 5,
                  }
              },
          ]
      },
  ]
```

I want to retrieve the id property of items array and put it an array so the expected output is ['1','2','3']

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
arr_obj.map(obj=>obj.items.map(item=>item.id)).flat()
```

- [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) loops over every item in an array and runs a transformation function on them, generating a new array.
- [`.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) flattens a multi-dimensional array into a 1d array

I'd suggest looking into [some of the other array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), as they are very useful.

---

You could even improve this slightly with `flatMap`:

```js
arr_obj.flatMap(obj=>obj.items.map(item=>item.id))
```

Comment: thanks. how can i do the same in python.